# How to use TextInput in Python using QML?

Tags: python, qml, pyside

I try to make a simple calculator using QML GUI with Python. When I give some values like (a=4, b=6, c=a+b) and click button, It can give a result. But I can't manage TextInput boxes in python. How to use text input boxes in Python when I give values to the input boxes?
Thanks

QML GUI:

http://postimg.org/image/o9wt326g5/

QML code:

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
    id:r
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: 200
    height: 200

    signal messageRequired;
    function updateMessage(text) {
        messageText.text = text
    }
    Column{
        width: r.width*0.8
        height: r.height*0.8
        spacing: 10

        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Row{
            id:ro
            spacing:10
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: ro.parent
                font.bold: true
                text: "a"
            }
            TextInput {
                id: a
                width: r.width*3/4
                height: 20
                selectionColor: "#2f8bc5"
                fillColor: "lightgray"
                font.bold: true
            }

        }

        Row{
            spacing:10
        Text {
            text: "b"
            font.bold: true
            }
        TextInput {
            id: b
            width: r.width*3/4
            height: 20
            fillColor: "lightgray"
            font.bold: true
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: calculate
            width: r.width
            height: 30
            color: "#8a0800"

            Text{
                anchors.centerIn: calculate
                font.bold: true
                text:"calculate";color:"white"
                }


            MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked:messageRequired()
        }

            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop {position: 0; color: "#8a0800"}
                GradientStop {position: 1; color: "#330009"}
            }
        }
        Row{
            spacing:10
        Text {
            text: "c"
            font.bold: true
        }
        TextInput {
            id: messageText

            font.bold: true
            width: r.width*3/4
            height: 20
            fillColor: "lightgray"
            selectionColor: "#2f8bc5"
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }}}}
```

And Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import math
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtDeclarative import QDeclarativeView

# Create Qt application and the QDeclarative view
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#------------------------------------
a=6
b=4
c=a+b
#------------------------------------------
class Now(QObject):
    now = Signal(str)
    def emit_now(self):
        formatted_date = str(c)
        self.now.emit(formatted_date)

now = Now()
#------------------------------------
qt_view = QDeclarativeView()
qt_view.setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView.SizeRootObjectToView)
# Create an URL to the QML file
url = QUrl('view.qml')
# Set the QML file and show
qt_view.setSource(url)
qt_view.show()
rootObject = qt_view.rootObject()

rootObject.messageRequired.connect(now.emit_now)

now.now.connect(rootObject.updateMessage)
# Enter Qt main loop
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```